# R error: 'match' requires vector arguments - package function with S4 object (raster) as parameter, and operator %in%

Tags: r, package, match, raster, r-s4

My goal is simply to use the %in% operator to compare the values in a raster object with the values I have in a vector.

This works fine, straight from the console:

```
values(raster(rbind(c(2,6,7,8),c(4,5,6,7),c(3,4,7,5),c(1,23,1,6))) %in% c(2,5,7))

 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

However I need a function inside a package I'm developing, and I have the following code:

```
test_lst <- function( rst) {
    return ( rst %in% c( 2, 5, 7))
}
```

When I load the package and call the function:

```
devtools::load_all( ".")
test_lst( raster( rbind( c( 2, 6, 7, 8),
                         c( 4, 5, 6, 7),
                         c( 3, 4, 7, 5),
                         c( 1, 23,1, 6))))
```

What I get is the following error:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
'match' requires vector arguments
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. 'raster' is declared in the imports section of the description file.

Comment: I think you just forgot to call `values` at some point (either give `values(raster(...))` to `test_lst` or have `test_lst` itself call `values` on its argument before computation)

Comment: If I call  `values(rst) %in% c( 2, 5, 7) ` it works, but that is not what I really need. I need to call  `rst %in% c( 2, 5, 7) `, and then call any raster function (in fact I used values here just to print the TRUE/FALSE values instead of a raster output. I could call  `values ` then rebuild the raster as a workaround, but I'm trying to figure out why `%in%` works for a raster object but fails when called in a function from a package.

Comment: fine — I know nothing about rasters, but the reason you got that error message was that `%in%` (which calls `match`) requires a vector, and a `raster` object isn't a vector. Calling `values` first turns it into a vector. You may be able to use other methods that have been defined for `raster` class objects, or feed one of the slots of the raster object into `%in%` instead of the whole raster object (I don't know if the raster stores its values in a slot or not).

Comment: Thanks for the help JDL. I believe I found the problem. The raster package extends the `%in%` operator so it works with raster objects. But for some reason I don't understand as I'm quite inexperienced on package development, the function calls the  operator from the base package. The solution would be to use `return (raster::\`%in%\`(rst, c(2,5,7)))`.

Comment: Can you check that `isS4(object)` returns `TRUE` where `object` is the raster object you are working with? `%in%` will probably not call a custom method if neither of its arguments is an S4 object.

Comment: `isS4` returns TRUE  indeed, from console and inside the `test_lst` function.